# Julia debugger in Jupyter or Org mode?

Tags: julia, jupyter, org-mode, org-babel, gallium

I use Julia for academic research and I use [literate analysis](https://www.turing.ac.uk/events/masterclass-literate-programming-data-science/): text,  code, and results live in the same document, and the results in sync with the code (similar to R-markdown, e.g. in RStudio). I can have the files in either Emacs Org-mode with Org-babel or in Jupyter with IJulia. I tried the [Gallium debugger](https://github.com/Keno/Gallium.jl) and it works well in a shell session, but not in Emacs or Jupyter. In both cases I get:

```
ERROR: UndefVarError: active_repl not defined
Stacktrace:
 [1] RunDebugger(::Array{ASTInterpreter2.JuliaStackFrame,1}) at ~/.julia/v0.6/DebuggerFramework/src/DebuggerFramework.jl:238
```

Does anyone have a solution to combine literate analysis and code debugging in Julia?

Comment: I can reproduce but have no idea how to solve the issue.

Comment: Looks like Base.active_repl is defined in `base/client.jl` when starting up the default REPL, and Gallium assumes it will be defined and available. Issue 163 in Gallium's repository (https://github.com/Keno/Gallium.jl/issues/163) seems related, perhaps you could add your situation there.